# how to get the position in the array based on the max values in bimodal histogram

Tags: arrays

For example:

say i have an array like this:

sampleArray = [1,1,1,3,4,4,4,**5**,4,4,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,**6**,5,5,4,4,3,2,2,1,1,0]

Is there a method to find the position of value 5 and 6 which are position 7 and 17 from the array? What i can relate from the position is to get min position & max value for position 7 and max position & max value for position 17

What I have is only to get the max value from the array.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate through the array with a for loop and check, whether the current number is what you are looking for (i.e. 5 or 6).

Comment: at the moment, i just put the number as example. Currently i have any number from the output but still it is a bimodal type. If the number in the array already there, it might be like suggested above. Right now i do not know the max number for both sides.

Comment: @ZMS If I understand correctly, then your array is already in a bimodal state,  so, while iterating through the array, you could keep track of the order of 2 numbers that are next to each other to see if they are in an ascending or descending order. The first part of the array is in ascending order, when you encounter the first descent, you have found the first maximum. Then you keep iterating and try to find the second maximum in the same way.

Comment: @Arturs .. thanks for info but there are some occurrence from the data can be like this. It had descent but go up again     {1,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,4,3,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,4,5,4,4,3,2,1,1,1} . it is still look bimodal but only not so clean signal.